# AWS API Gateway HTTP API CORS preflight request

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm using the new API Gateway HTTP to make requests to 3rd party APIs. This works great for GET requests but doesn't work for POST requests due to CORS preflight.

[image: Cors settings in api gateway]

When I try to make a request this is the error I get on the chrome console...

[image: Preflight error]

From the docs it says to add Access-Control-Allow-Methods to * and Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * but POST requests triggers a pre flight request and this is failing.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Get works fine but not POST. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Still having the same issue and glad I'm not the only one experiencing this. Hope the AWS team looks into this...

Comment: Same problem here. I switched to AWS REST API to get CORS working.

Comment: Anybody found a solution to that? Can't be true that it is not possible to setup the AWS HTTP API with working CORS...

Answer (score 2):

Double-check your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. If it's missing any headers that are sent on the request it will silently fail.

I had the same issue (works for `GET` but not `POST`) because I had forgotten to add the `content-type` header to the list. This is a common header sent with `POST` requests and I can see it is missing in your example.

It may also help to examine the failed network requests in the browser console to see which headers are being sent.

Comment: This was it. After hours of scraping AWS docs and reading blogs that mix up the HTTP and REST flavors of API Gateway, you solved my issue. Thanks!